# Perl script to remove line from one pipe-separated file using another file have one matching column

Tags: perl

I have two huge files, `File A` containing all records as pipe (`|`) separated columns, and `File B` which has one column.

I need to remove all lines from `File A` where that one column value matches with `File B`.

I want Column number 1 from File B to be checked against column number 2 in FILE A

File B - Only Column in File B

```
818815504
842019301
880702511
```

File A - 2nd Column in FIle A

```
2020-01-19|777504559|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|5033|127380343|0|3905585|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|818815504|2|15|1|403933|8|2394063|3036|2394067|4076948618|0|15177438|B|1168|CRU|98|NK
2020-01-19|842019301|2|15|1|2|2|3712|3036|961249|65707843|65707843|8591573|B|1168|IRU|1|NJ
2020-01-19|847082255|2|15|1|2|2|284|3036|291|125650195|125650195|8870299|C|1168|IRU|1|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|306|99931425|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|869323039|2|15|1|2|2|371|3036|307|106104029|106104029|4518435|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
2020-01-19|872268371|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|143|127382679|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|2|2|117|3036|109|2739523|5208959|4037061|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include example input demonstrating what `File A` and `File B` look like. Also, which column of `File A` needs to match the value in `File B` to merit a deletion? Do you only want to delete the line in `File A` if any column matches the value _on the same line_ in `File B`, or would a match with any line in `File B` lead to the deletion of thet line in `File A`?

Comment: Thanks for Showing interest in my Query 
i have edited my post to answer your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the ordering of the result is unimportant:

```
$ join -v 1 -t '|' -1 2 <( sort -t '|' -k2,2 fileA ) <( sort fileB )
777504559|2020-01-19|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|5033|127380343|0|3905585|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
847082255|2020-01-19|2|15|1|2|2|284|3036|291|125650195|125650195|8870299|C|1168|IRU|1|NR
858760375|2020-01-19|2|15|1|2|2|117|3036|109|2739523|5208959|4037061|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
858760375|2020-01-19|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|306|99931425|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
869323039|2020-01-19|2|15|1|2|2|371|3036|307|106104029|106104029|4518435|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
872268371|2020-01-19|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|143|127382679|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
```

The `join` utility performs a relational INNER JOIN operation on the two datasets given.  The datasets must be sorted on the columns that we join on, which is why we sort the files before calling `join` (if your shell does not support process substitutions, pre-sort the files separately). The options that we use with `join` here, `-t '|'` and `-1 2`, means "use `|` as the column delimiter, and join on the second column of the first dataset" (the first column is otherwise the default).

With `-v 1` we request all lines from the first file that can't be paired with the lines from the second file.

The output will always list the join column first, so we may want to move that into its correct position by swapping the two first columns using `awk`:

```
$ join -v 1 -t '|' -1 2 <( sort -t '|' -k2,2 fileA ) <( sort fileB ) | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print }'
2020-01-19|777504559|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|5033|127380343|0|3905585|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|847082255|2|15|1|2|2|284|3036|291|125650195|125650195|8870299|C|1168|IRU|1|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|2|2|117|3036|109|2739523|5208959|4037061|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|306|99931425|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|869323039|2|15|1|2|2|371|3036|307|106104029|106104029|4518435|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
2020-01-19|872268371|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|143|127382679|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
```

---

Using `awk` only:

```
$ awk -F '|' 'FNR==NR { key[$1]=1; next } !($2 in key)' fileB fileA
2020-01-19|777504559|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|5033|127380343|0|3905585|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|847082255|2|15|1|2|2|284|3036|291|125650195|125650195|8870299|C|1168|IRU|1|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|306|99931425|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|869323039|2|15|1|2|2|371|3036|307|106104029|106104029|4518435|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
2020-01-19|872268371|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|143|127382679|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|2|2|117|3036|109|2739523|5208959|4037061|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
```

This first reads the number that we want to extract into the associative array `key`.  Then, when the second file is parsed, if the 2nd field is not a key in that array, the line is printed.

This will output the lines from `fileA` in the order that they occur in that file, but the downside is that all numbers from `fileB` needs to be kept in memory.

---

Using Perl, as requested:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -le 'if (!$flag){ $key{$F[0]}=1 } elsif ($key{$F[1]}!=1) { print $_ }; if (!$flag && eof) { $flag=1 };' fileB fileA
2020-01-19|777504559|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|5033|127380343|0|3905585|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|847082255|2|15|1|2|2|284|3036|291|125650195|125650195|8870299|C|1168|IRU|1|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|306|99931425|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|869323039|2|15|1|2|2|371|3036|307|106104029|106104029|4518435|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
2020-01-19|872268371|2|15|1|403941|53|4708267|3036|143|127382679|0|8866849|C|1168|IRU|107|NR
2020-01-19|858760375|2|15|1|2|2|117|3036|109|2739523|5208959|4037061|C|1168|IRU|2|NR
```

This mimics the `awk` program, but since Perl does not have separate `NR` and `FNR` built-in variables, we need to maintain some state (`$flag`) that tells us whether we are currently parsing the first or second file.

Comment: I am new to unix ,but i tried executing all options but it didnt work 
--perl option just cam out without doing anything to file
--awk is giving syntax error

Comment: @AniketKhandagale Then you've mistyped something, or your data does not look like you've shown. As you can see, it works for me, and I'm not using anything that shouldn't be supported on most types of Unix systems.  If you have a particular setup (AIX, Solaris, some embedded system running `busybox` or other), then you need to let us know about these limitations.  For the `awk` solution I've tested the code with OpenBSD `awk`, GNU `awk` and with `mawk`.

Comment: i am typing as it is you have given , all 3 option , but some home its not working

Comment: @AniketKhandagale If you are working with DOS text files, you may want to convert them to Unix text files with `dos2unix`. If they are DOS text files, there will be an invisible carriage-return character at the end of each line, which would mess up the reading of `fileB` (in particular).  I'm also interested in knowing what the error you got from `awk` said. It's a bit difficult to debug _anything_ without knowing exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: ]/opt/app/d1ltp1c3/oerpops/inbound/bin/ANIKS/SAH/TEST>awk -F '|' 'FNR==NR { key[$1]=1; next } !($2 in key)' dee.txt subsrptn_actvt_hist.20200118.dat
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: No error on perl , but i just comes out without doing anything , and join just doesnt end i even tried with smaller files

Comment: @AniketKhandagale What does `awk --version` output? Does the `join` or `perl` variations work if you _copy and paste_ the data from your own question?

Comment: perl and join variation , did not work even after copying every from question as it is

Comment: awk --version , got stuck , so i tried below option

Comment: /opt/app/d1ltp1c3/oerpops/inbound/bin/ANIKS/SAH/TEST>awk -V &>/dev/null && echo gawk || echo nawk
[2]     20006
gawk

Comment: /opt/app/d1ltp1c3/oerpops/inbound/bin> uname -a

SunOS bsdev05 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

Comment: @AniketKhandagale Ok, so the fact that you are on Solaris 10 makes a difference.  You should be using `gawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: Thanks for your great help and it worked fine when i used nawk , tell me if it makes any difference ?

Comment: @AniketKhandagale The default `awk` program on Solaris is written before the `awk` language was standardised. Solaris includes it for backward compatibility. The `nawk` ("New `awk`", which is the same as `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`) is a more usable `awk` implementation. You can pick up that newer `awk` by making sure that `/usr/xpg4/bin` is first in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Great Information , learned so many new things today ! Thanks again for your great great help.

We had shell script to do this job using grep , but it was estimated arround 5 Hrs , due to high volume of data. but your awk option worked in 7 minutes. :) Thanks again